# A question about pdfs with likelihood ratio order

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, order-theory

Suppose $f_1,f_2,\dots$ are pdfs of absolutely continuous random variables with the same support (say an interval). Assume that $\{f_i\}$ are strictly positive in their support. Furthermore, $\frac{f_i(x)}{f_j(x)}$ is increasing in $x$ for any $i<j$. This is sometimes called the likelihood ratio order.

Let $t_i= \arg\max_p F^{-1}_{i+1}(p) - F^{-1}_i(p)$. Here $F^{-1}_i$ is the inverse function of the CDF associated with random variable i.

Is $\{t_i\}$ an increasing sequence? Is it a decreasing sequence? If not, can you provide counterexamples?

Comment: you may want to define $F_i^{-1}$ --- inverse function, reciprocal, cdf ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It was forgotten. The question is now updated.

Comment: updated; I mean inverse function.

Comment: I assume that pdfs are always positive, and the random variables are continuous.

Comment: Does $t_i= \arg\max_p F^{-1}_{i+1}(p) - F^{-1}_i(p)$ mean $t_i= \arg\max_p (F^{-1}_{i+1}(p) - F^{-1}_i(p))$?

Comment: Does "Is it an increasing/decreasing sequence?" mean the following two questions: (i) "Is it an increasing sequence?" and (ii) "Is it a decreasing sequence?" ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Updated.